# What's the problem with this recursive case?

Tags: c++, recursion

> guys I faced a problem with the recursive case of a power of a number given its base and exponent. Why is it not working properly and returns 0 everytime?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std; 
int qn(int n,int q)  
    if(q==1)
        return 0; 
    return n*qn(n,q-1);
}
int main() {
    cout << qn(2,2); 
}
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a valid problem statement.  What is it doing, and what do you expect it to do?

Comment: I have to perform a recursive power of  a number

Comment: Your indentation is not representative of the code's logic.  I suggest, as a first step, that you include all the requisite braces, and indent your code properly.

Comment: You probably meant `return 1;` instead of `return 0;`.

Comment: Why is it multiplied by 0 at the end I mean (when I return 0 in the base case)?

Comment: possybly, `qn` for a function and `n, q` for parameter names are so bad that compilers refuses to produce a good program. Joking apart, use meaningful names for functions and variables

Answer (score 1):

You return 0 at the end of the recursion, and multiply with that value. Will always yield 0.

Answer (score 0):

**Seriously, this is very easy to figure out using only a pencil and some paper.**

- `qn(2, 2)` called
- `q` is 2 so you execute `n * qn(n, q - 1)`
- Replacing values you have `2 * qn(2, 1)`
- `qn(2, 1)` called
- `q` is 1, so `if (q == 1)` is true
- thus 0 is returned
- You remplace `qn(2, 1)` by 0 in `2 * qn(2, 1)`
- You have `2 * 0`
- That give `0`

If you use a debugger, this is even easier as you can execute the program step by step and simply note everythings it does.

By the way, as written, your code would not even compile because an opening `{` is missing after `int qn(int n,int q)`.